# Realtek-8723DE-wifi module in kernel

Tags: wireless, kernel

Hp-15 laptop (fairly recent and popular W10 model) has Realtek-8723DE WiFi adapter. The driver module is not part of any current 4-15.0 kernels of Ubuntu 18.04. Every time there is a kernel update (presently to -39) I have to recompile the module. My question is: when will be this module be part of the kernel updates?

Comment: Whenever mainline devs think it is stable enough, ...probably never in 4.15.

Comment: Where did you get the source code from?

Comment: git clone -b extended --single-branch https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: After running the git command a folder will be created in the directory where git command was invoked. The folder name created by git is rtlwifi_new. Then open terminal in that folder, run sudo make, sudo make install and sudo modprobe -v rtl8723de ant_sel=2. Finally run sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf'. This last command assures that the wifi module antenna has good sensitivity. This has worked for me.